# How to get XY value from ct in Philips Hue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, philips-hue, cct

How to get XY value from ct.

**Ex:** ct = 217, I want to get x="0.3127569", y= "0.32908".

I'm able to convert XY value into ct value using this below code.

```
        float R1 = [hue[0] floatValue];
        float S1 = [hue[1] floatValue];
        
        float result = ((R1-0.332)/(S1-0.1858));
        
        NSString *ctString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ((-449*result*result*result)+(3525*result*result)-(6823.3*result)+(5520.33))];
        
        float micro2 = (float) (1 / [ctString floatValue] * 1000000);
        
        NSString *ctValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", micro2];
        ctValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [ctValue intValue]];
        if ([ctValue integerValue] < 153) {
            ctValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 153];
        }
```

Now I want reverse value, which is from ct to XY.

Comment: Does this help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation

Comment: @skaak: what that should help? The question is about colours

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi question is about inverting equations ... not sure if that will help but the math denseness is about the same ...

Comment: no chance of a reverse. see `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", micro2] intValue]]` in your code, loss of precision

Comment: That is more or less ```640 320 ^ 3 + 744 = e ^ [ pi . sqrt( 163 ) ]```

Comment: CIE 1931 xy to CCT Formula after McCamy `n= (x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y); CCT = 437*n^3 + 3601*n^2 + 6861*n + 5517` this up there looks pretty much like a CCT formula

Comment: Yes must be CCT, also if taken in context with the *other* question. Mine is almost integer, aka Ramanujan's constant ...

Answer (score 1):

On Phillips HUE
2000K maps to 500 and 6500K maps to 153 
given in `ct` as color temperature but can be thought as actually being `Mired`. 
Mired means `micro reciprocal degree` [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mired).

`ct` is possibly used because it is not 100% Mired. Quite sure Phillips uses a lookup table as a lot CIE algorithms do because there are just 347 indexes in this range from 153 to 500.

The following is not a solution, it's just simple concept of a lookup table.
And as the CIE 1931 xy to CCT Formula by McCamy suggests [found here](https://www.waveformlighting.com/tech/calculate-color-temperature-cct-from-cie-1931-xy-coordinates) it is possible to use a lookup table to find x and y as well.
A table can be found [here](https://www.waveformlighting.com/files/blackBodyLocus_1.txt) but i am not sure if that is the right lookup table.

*reminder* so the following is not a solution, but to find an reverse algo the code may help.

```
typedef int Kelvin;
typedef float Mired;

Mired linearMiredByKelvin(Kelvin k) {
    if (k==0) return 0;
    return 1000000.0/k;
}

-(void)mired {
    Mired miredMin = 2000.0/13.0; // 153,84 = reciprocal 6500K
    Mired miredMax = 500.0;       // 500,00 = reciprocal 2000K
    
    Mired lookupMiredByKelvin[6501]; //max 6500 Kelvin + 1 safe index
    //Kelvin lookupKelvinByMired[501]; //max 500 Mired + 1 safe index
    
    // dummy stuff, empty unused table space
    for (Kelvin k = 0; k < 2000; k++) {
        lookupMiredByKelvin[k] = 0;
    }
    //for (Mired m = 0.0; m < 154.0; m++) {
    //    lookupKelvinByMired[(int)m] = 0;
    //}
    
    for (Kelvin k=2000; k<6501; k++) {
        Mired linearMired = linearMiredByKelvin(k);
        float dimm = (linearMired - miredMin) / ( miredMax - miredMin);
        Kelvin ct = (Kelvin)(1000000.0/(dimm*miredMax - dimm*miredMin + miredMin));
        lookupMiredByKelvin[k] = linearMiredByKelvin(ct);
        if (k==2000 || k==2250 || k==2500 || k==2750 ||
            k==3000 || k==3250 || k==3500 || k==3750 ||
            k==4000 || k==4250 || k==4500 || k==4750 ||
            k==5000 || k==5250 || k==5500 || k==5750 ||
            k==6000 || k==6250 || k==6500 || k==6501 )
            fprintf(stderr,"%d %f %f\n",ct, dimm, lookupMiredByKelvin[k]);
    }
}
```

at least this is proof that x and y will not sit on a simple vector.

[image]

`CCT` means `correlated colour temperature` and like the implementation in the question shows can be calculated via `n= (x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y); CCT = 437*n^3 + 3601*n^2 + 6861*n + 5517`. *(after McCamy)*

but a `cct=217` is out of range of above link'ed lookup table.

following the idea in this git-repo from [colour-science](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/temperature/cie_d.py)
and ported to C it could look like..

```
void CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(float cct) {
    //if (CCT < 4000 || CCT > 25000) fprintf(stderr, "Correlated colour temperature must be in domain, unpredictable results may occur! \n");
    float x =  calculateXviaCCT(cct);
    float y = calculateYviaX(x);
    NSLog(@"cct=%f x%f y%f",cct,x,y);
}

float calculateXviaCCT(float cct) {
    float cct_3 = pow(cct, 3); //(cct*cct*cct);
    float cct_2 = pow(cct, 2); //(cct*cct);
    if (cct<=7000)
    return -4.607 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 + 2.9678 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.09911 * pow(10, 3) / cct + 0.244063;
    return -2.0064 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 + 1.9018 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.24748 * pow(10, 3) / cct + 0.23704;
}
float calculateYviaX(float x) {
    return -3.000 * pow(x, 2) + 2.870 * x - 0.275;
}

CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(6504.38938305); //proof of concept
//cct=6504.389160 x0.312708 y0.329113

CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(217.0); 
//cct=217.000000 x-387.131073 y-450722.750000
// so for sure Phillips hue temperature given in ct between 153-500 is not a good starting point

//but
CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(2000.0);
//cct=2000.000000 x0.459693 y0.410366
```

this seems to work fine with CCT between 2000 and 25000, but maybe confusing is CCT is given in Kelvin here.

Comment: You cracked it! Nice - working on it as well ... now I can rest, I started with your cubic equation ...

Comment: na i think not yet, but time for a cofé

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This has been through so many revisions and ideas. To keep it simple I edited most of that out and just give you the final result.

This fits your function perfectly except for a region in the middle (temp from 256 to 316) where it deviates a bit.

The problem with your function is that it has approximately infinite solutions, so to solve it nicely you need more constraints, but what? Ol Sen's reference https://www.waveformlighting.com/tech/calculate-color-temperature-cct-from-cie-1931-xy-coordinates discusses it in some detail and then mentions that you want a `Duv` to be zero. It also gives a way to calculate Duv and so I added that to my optimiser and voila!

Nice and smooth. The optimiser now solves for x and y that both satisfies your function and also minimises Duv.

To get it to work nicely I had to scale Duv quite a bit. That page mentions that Duv should be very small so I think this is a good thing. Also, as the temp increases the scaling should to help the optimiser.

Below prints from 153 to 500.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// Function taken from your code
// Simplified a bit
int ctFuncI ( float x, float y )
{
    // float R1 = [hue[0] floatValue];
    // float S1 = [hue[1] floatValue];
    float result = (x-0.332)/(y-0.1858);
    float cubic  = - 449 * result * result * result + 3525 * result * result - 6823.3 * result + 5520.33;
    float micro2 = 1 / cubic * 1000000;
    int ct = ( int )( micro2 + 0.5 );
    
    if ( ct < 153 )
    {
        ct = 153;
    }
    
    return ct;
}

// Need this
// Float version of your code
float ctFuncF ( float x, float y )
{
    // float R1 = [hue[0] floatValue];
    // float S1 = [hue[1] floatValue];
    float result = (x-0.332)/(y-0.1858);
    float cubic  = - 449 * result * result * result + 3525 * result * result - 6823.3 * result + 5520.33;

    return 1000000 / cubic;
}

// We need an additional constraint
// https://www.waveformlighting.com/tech/calculate-duv-from-cie-1931-xy-coordinates
// Given x, y calculate Duv
// We want this to be 0
float duv ( float x, float y )
{
    float f = 1 / ( - 2 * x + 12 * y + 3 );
    float u = 4 * x * f;
    float v = 6 * y * f;

    // I'm typing float but my heart yells double
    float k6 = -0.00616793;
    float k5 =  0.0893944;
    float k4 = -0.5179722;
    float k3 =  1.5317403;
    float k2 = -2.4243787;
    float k1 =  1.925865;
    float k0 = -0.471106;
    
    float du = u - 0.292;
    float dv = v - 0.24;

    float Lfp = sqrt ( du * du + dv * dv );
    float a = acos( du / Lfp );
    float Lbb = k6 * pow ( a, 6 ) + k5 * pow( a, 5 ) + k4 * pow( a, 4 ) + k3 * pow( a, 3 ) + k2 * pow(a,2) + k1 * a + k0;

    return Lfp - Lbb;
}

// Solver!
// Returns iterations
int ctSolve ( int ct, float * x, float * y )
{
    int iter = 0;
    float dx = 0.001;
    float dy = 0.001;

    // Error
    // Note we scale duv a bit
    // Seems the higher the temp, the higher scale we require
    // Also note the jump at 255 ...
    float s = 1000 * ( ct > 255 ? 10 : 1 );
    float d = fabs( ctFuncF ( * x, * y ) - ct ) + s * fabs( duv ( * x, * y ) );
    
    // Approx
    while ( d > 0.5 && iter < 250 )
    {
        iter ++;

        dx *= fabs( ctFuncF ( * x + dx, * y ) - ct ) + s * fabs( duv ( * x + dx, * y ) ) < d ? 1.2 : - 0.5;
        dy *= fabs( ctFuncF ( * x, * y + dy ) - ct ) + s * fabs( duv ( * x, * y + dy ) ) < d ? 1.2 : - 0.5;

        * x += dx;
        * y += dy;

        d = fabs( ctFuncF ( * x, * y ) - ct ) + s * fabs( duv ( * x, * y ) );
    }

    return iter;
}

// Tester
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        float x, y;
        int sume = 0;
        int sumi = 0;
                
        for ( int ct = 153; ct <= 500; ct ++ )
        {
            // Initial guess
            x = 0.4;
            y = 0.4;

            // Approx
            int iter = ctSolve ( ct, & x, & y );
            
            // CT and error
            int ctEst = ctFuncI ( x, y );
            int e = ct - ctEst;
            
            // Diagnostics
            sume += abs ( e );
            sumi += iter;
            
            // Print out results
            NSLog ( @"want ct = %d x = %f y = %f got ct %d in %d iter error %d", ct, x, y, ctEst, iter, e );
        }
        
        NSLog ( @"Sum of abs errors %d iterations %d", sume, sumi );

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

To use it, do as below.

```
// To call it, init x and y to some guess
float x = 0.4;
float y = 0.4;

// Then call solver with your temp
int ct = 217;

ctSolve( ct, & x, & y ); // Note you pass references to x and y

// Done, answer now in x and y
```

Comment: i like it. the problem of the problem.. :-D

Answer (score 0):

a bit more compact answer and functions to convert back and forth..
beware there are rounding issues because McCamy's [formula](https://www.waveformlighting.com/tech/calculate-color-temperature-cct-from-cie-1931-xy-coordinates) relies and mathematical assumptions. And so the backward calculation does also.

if you want to find more results search directly for `"n= (x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y); CCT = 437*n^3 + 3601*n^2 + 6861*n + 5517"` there are plenty of different methods to convert back and forth.

so here `Phillips-Hue @[@x,@y]` to `Phillips-ct`,
`Phillips-ct` to `CCT`,
 `CCT` to `x,y`

```
void CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(float cct) {
    //if (CCT < 4000 || CCT > 25000) fprintf(stderr, "Correlated colour temperature must be in domain, unpredictable results may occur! \n");
    float x = calculateXviaCCT(cct);
    float y = calculateYviaX(x);
    fprintf(stderr,"cct=%f x%f y%f",cct,x,y);
}
float calculateXviaCCT(float cct) {
    float cct_3 = pow(cct, 3); //(cct*cct*cct);
    float cct_2 = pow(cct, 2); //(cct*cct);
    if (cct<=7000.0)
    return -4.607 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 + 2.9678 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.09911 * pow(10, 3) / cct + 0.244063;
    return -2.0064 * pow(10, 9) / cct_3 + 1.9018 * pow(10, 6) / cct_2 + 0.24748 * pow(10, 3) / cct + 0.23704;
}
float calculateYviaX(float x) {
    return -3.000 * x*x + 2.870 * x - 0.275;
}
int calculate_PhillipsHueCT_withCCT(float cct) {
    if (cct>6500.0) return 2000.0/13.0;
    if (cct<2000.0) return 500.0;
    //return (float) (1 / cct * 1000000); // same as..
    return 1000000 / cct;
}
float calculate_CCT_withPhillipsHueCT(float ct) {
    if (ct == 0.0) return 0.0;
    return 1000000 / ct;
}
float calculate_CCT_withHueXY(NSArray *hue) {
    float x = [hue[0] floatValue]; //R1
    float y = [hue[1] floatValue]; //S1
    //x = 0.312708; y = 0.329113;
    float n = (x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y);
    float cct = 437.0*n*n*n + 3601.0*n*n + 6861.0*n + 5517.0;
    return cct;
}

// MC Camy formula n=(x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y); cct = 437*n^3 + 3601*n^2 + 6861*n + 5517;
-(void)testPhillipsHueCt_backAndForth {
    NSArray *hue = @[@(0.312708),@(0.329113)];
    
    float cct = calculate_CCT_withHueXY(hue);

    float ct = calculate_PhillipsHueCT_withCCT(cct);
    NSLog(@"ct %f",ct);
    
    CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(cct); // check
    
    CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(6504.38938305); //proof of concept

    CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(2000.0);
    
    CCT_to_xy_CIE_D(calculate_CCT_withPhillipsHueCT(217.0));
}
```

Comment: Nice - error is large around 2000 ... what is range here? 2000 - 6500?

Comment: yes.. 2000 - 6500, actually 2000-25000. below its very "flatulent", even if stil kinda logical.

Comment: I was thinking to convert this to 153 - 500 range. If I run this from 2000 - 6500 and use OP's formula I get 154 - 371 with 154 on the 6500 side, so even if I do 2000 - 25000 it will stay that range. Anyhow ... you said flatulent ...

Comment: the fun is forward to CCT and back from CT its the same formula 1000000/ (ct or cct), see `calculate_PhillipsHueCT_withCCT()` and `calculate_CCT_withPhillipsHueCT()`

Comment: Yes noted that ... I ran CT from 2000 - 6500 to get x and y and then plugged that into OP's and got OP CT from 154 - 371 just FWIW ...

Comment: OP didn't use McCamy but pretty close ... I'm looking at using U and V to correct as OP formula has many solutions, so I need more constraints, seems way to resolve it is to set Duv = 0 ...